# Can't install npm module on docker machine

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, phantomjs, dockerfile

I'm new to Docker and I faced with a problem on windows, 
I get an error while running `npm i` on my docker machine:

```
panel_1  | > phantomjs-prebuilt@2.1.16 install /var/www/html/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt
panel_1  | > node install.js
panel_1  |
panel_1  | module.js:550
panel_1  |     throw err;
panel_1  |     ^
panel_1  |
panel_1  | Error: Cannot find module 'readable-stream'
panel_1  |     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:548:15)
panel_1  |     at Function.Module._load (module.js:475:25)
panel_1  |     at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
panel_1  |     at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
panel_1  |     at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/html/node_modules/concat-stream/index.js:1:78)
panel_1  |     at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
panel_1  |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
panel_1  |     at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
panel_1  |     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
panel_1  |     at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
```

My compose:

```
  panel:
    build: './panel'
    volumes:
      - ./panel:/var/www/html
    command: make init_dev
```

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.2-fpm

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    openssl \
    git \
    unzip \
    libzip-dev \
    wget \
    gnupg

# NodeJs
RUN wget -qO- https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | bash -

RUN apt-get install -y nodejs
RUN apt-get install -y build-essential

# Composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli pdo pdo_mysql zip bcmath

WORKDIR /var/www/html
```

makefile init_dev:

```
composer install
npm i
npm run dev
```

Already spent a day on resolving it. I tried to downgrade Phantomjs / upgrade npm / change permission for global node_modules but nothing helped.
On local it's OK.

---

Just found that npm installation goes successful without using `volumes` .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems it happens due to windows mounted folder. Because there are no support for symlinks which npm is trying to add.
My workaround looks like this:

```
COPY . /var/www/temp

WORKDIR /var/www/temp

RUN npm i

WORKDIR /var/www/html
```

And then I just do a copy of finished modules with CMD:

```
cp -r ../temp/node_modules ./
```

Looks like a crutch, but mb it'll help somebody